# Syntax for local variable absolute to another variable with some offset

Tags: delphi

Is there a way that I can declare a variable with an absolute address that has some offset to the variable that it refers to. For instance, instead of:

```
function RefCount(const s: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := PInteger(Integer(s) - 8)^;
end;
```

is there some way that I can do:

```
function RefCount(const s: string): Integer;
var
  Count: PInteger absolute s {- 8 ?} ;
begin
  Result := Count^;
end;
```

(The example is to illustrate only, it is not necessarily useful..)

Comment: I asked the same question on WP:RD/C a few years ago, and the answer I got there was 'no'. And, as far as I know, that really *is* the answer.

Comment: (By the way, you do know that your first snippet is actually shorter than your last one, right? :)

Comment: What you are basically asking for is the equivilent of VC++'s `__based` keyword.  There is no such feature in Delphi (or C++Builder, for that matter).

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, second one is (or, actually, would be) more declarative than generic pointer arithmetics.

Comment: I'd look for another way to accomplish whatever it is you're actually trying to do. While you might be able to figure out a way to shuffle pointers around, this is a horrible can of worms to open, breaking all kinds of best-practice rules. Perhaps if you gave us a little more context, we might be able to suggest a more appropriate solution.

Comment: The absolute doesn't work, but if it did, unless I'm misunderstanding, it would give you the effect of `Result := PInteger(Integer(@s) - 8)^;` which is completely wrong.

Comment: @hvd - I think it would give `PInteger(PInteger(Integer(@s) - 8)^)^` but I get your point.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, I think you corrected it correctly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think there is an 'extended syntax' of the `absolute` keyword. The documentation is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables#Absolute_Addresses), and, as far as I know, there are no undocumented features related to this keyword.

Comment: Thank you Andreas. While searching on the web what I noticed was 'absolute' isn't being used all that much at all. So I wasn't hoping for much..

Comment: `absolute` is only for declaring variables that share the same memory address, not for declaring variables that are offset from each other.

Answer (score 4):

There is no syntax for what you ask.

What you can do, however, is use pointer arithmetic (if you are using a version that supports it), eg:

```
function RefCount(const s: string): Integer; 
begin 
  if s <> '' then
    Result := (PInteger(s) - 2)^; 
  else
    Result := 0; 
end;
```

A more reliably approach is to use the `StrRec` record type instead, which is what a `String` actually contains internally:

```
function RefCount(const s: string): Integer; 
begin 
  if s <> '' then
    Result := (PStrRec(s) - 1)^.refCnt
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Or, the non pointer arithmetic version:

```
function RefCount(const s: string): Integer; 
begin 
  if s <> '' then
    Result := PStrRec(LongInt(s) - SizeOf(StrRec))^.refCnt
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

BTW, starting with D2009+, the `System` unit has its own `StringRefCount()` function that retreive a String's reference count.

Comment: Thank you Remy. My question wasn't particularly about reference count, it was just an example. Sorry if my example wasn't so good :). D2007 does not have pointer arithmetic, but I'll keep in mind 'PStrRec' for getting reference count from now on, it seems more correct then what I'm doing now (until I'll get a version that has 'StringRefCount').

Comment: If anybody wants to use 'StrRec', you have to declare the record, because it's in implementation section of 'system.pas'.

Comment: In Delphi 2007 and below you can use the `Inc` and `Dec` function to do pointer algorithmic.